# Status Bar and Bottom App Bar occlusion WP 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm using the following code to make the status bar appear on top of content (and setting background opacity = 0).

```
var applicationView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
applicationView.SetDesiredBoundsMode(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow);
```

This has the adverse affect of also making the bottom app bar overlap the page content. Is there a way to make the status bar overlap content, but not also the bottom app bar?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/f8KYpMu.png]

Comment: How are you showing the bottom menu? What is it?

Comment: It's just a grid that's vertically aligned bottom.