# The App content overlaps the status bar in Window 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, statusbar

I am creating the windows 8.1 phone project and I have a problem that the App content overlaps the status bar in Window 8.1 when clicking command bar and search box alternately. While clicking search box inbuilt keyboard appears and content goes up as in the screenshot:[image: problem].

The original view looks  like as below: [image: no problem]

Basic layout is
[image: xaml]

Comment: Is it WinRT or Silverlight project?

Comment: @ad1Dima The project is WinRT Windows 8.1 phone App

Comment: Can you show some xaml

Comment: @ad1Dima Basic layout is added to question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088947/status-bar-and-bottom-app-bar-occlusion-wp-8-1

Comment: Can you please copy the code in rather than an image of it.

Comment: this issue occurs in Nokia 625

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I see two cases:

1) you can hide StatusBar when searchbar got focus like this:

```
var sb = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
await sb.HideAsync();
```

2) You can setup whole app not to go under statusbar (and bottom on screen navbar) like this

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseVisible)
```

Comment: I used the second code you mentioned ApplicationView.SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseVisible) in the constructor of the page and not working.

Comment: @user7079177 lost .GetForCurrentView(). See updated answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088947/status-bar-and-bottom-app-bar-occlusion-wp-8-1

Comment: this issue occurs in Nokia 625